# Amazon Pay on Woocommerce error in Sandbox mode (InvalidOrderReferenceId)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, amazon-pay

I installed  the Amazon Pay plugin on my WordPress/Woocommerce website, left in in Sanbox mode, created a Sandbox test account and when I run a test transaction, I get a message that states "Invalid Payment Method"

When I go to the Woocommerce log, the error that I find is:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/OffAmazonPayments/2013-01-01">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidOrderReferenceId</Code>
    <Message>The OrderReferenceId S00-0000000-0000000 is invalid.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>646d0e3e-b603-420d-8178-ad20690fee41</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the Integration guide: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/eu/amazon-pay-onetime/intro.html
You would have to use an Amazon Generated Order ID from the Address widget. Please obtain it using the function:

```
onOrderReferenceCreate: function(orderReference) {
  // Here is where you can grab the Order Reference ID.
  orderReference.getAmazonOrderReferenceId();
},
```

You can use the orderReference ID anywhere from this point. Since, you are using WooCommerce SP, you can follow the integration guide too.

Thanks.